What is exact difference between npm run android and npm start/npm run start in react native application?
I am somewhat new to React Native and have a question about the differences between the commands "npm run android" (same as "npm react-native run-android") and "npm run start" (same as "npm react-native start"). For me, "npm run android" takes more time to initialize than "npm run start". Additionally, "npm run android" starts a new command prompt window.
I assume that both "npm run start" and "npm start" work the same way.
I tried searching the React Native official documentation but couldn't find the exact difference. I used the command "npm react-native@latest init MyApp" to create my React Native app. Also, React Native has removed the development environment docs in their latest version, 0.74.

"npm run android" and "npm run start" are not same but similar commands that serves the same purpose.
The package.json of React-Native app consists of following script:
"scripts":{
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },

Running 'npm run android ' will translate into first script i.e
'react-native run-android'. This command launches our app into connected device or emulator.
It initiates the Android build process using Gradle, which compiles the Java and Kotlin code, generates the APK (Android application package), and prepares the app for installation on the device or emulator
On the other hand 'npm run start' will execute fourth script i.e
'react-native start'. This command start 'Metro' which is a javascript bundler. It bundles together our react-native app with its dependencies and other assets like images.
We don't need to run 'npm run start' manually as 'npm run android' automatically starts the bundler.
